# How to shape an image from css

Tags: html, css

A tricky task assign to me.

My Problem is i have a squire image but i corp into from right side little bit.

Please see the example what i want exactly.

**My First original image**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vEDo.jpg)

**I want this type of cropped image from right side**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgIYn.png)

And this image is changeable from back-end so we can't set from css.

Please help me how to crop this image from css.

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: please provide some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div {
  transform: skewX(-10deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 3%;
  margin-left: -6%;
}

img {
  transform: skewX(10deg) translateX(6%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vEDo.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: " we can't set from css. " op

Comment: Thanks, Andrey Fedorov you done this job and help me.

Comment: @KaiEn "Please help me how to crop this image from css." I dont know...

Comment: @AndreyFedorov I sincerely offer my deepest apologies for the foolish mistake I have made. My command in the English Language is not strong and as such I seek knowledge from experts like you for. Once again, I do offer my sincerest apologies, as I do not intent to cause any physical or emotional damage. If my mistake has caused any inconveniences or psychological damage to you, I do apologise. I would also like to take this valuable opportunity to thank you for the short yet meaningful and educational learning experience.